# Visual Studio 2013 - Force renamed project files to commit automatically

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, commit

I have a project under git version control in Visual Studio. However when I change the name of files, These files do not get included for commits *automatically*. I know how to manually include them, but I am looking for an automatic solution.

For example:

[image]

In the pic, next to the two files I circled (which are the same files that were once included for commits, except I renamed them now), the 'lock' icon is not there, meaning that it is not 'checked in' for commits. **Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to do this automatically every time existing files are renamed in the project?**

I want to be able to do this only through Visual Studio's GUI, not through the command line. (If possible)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you add new files to the project *from within VisualStudio*, the Team Explorer should automatically detect that and add the file in the “Included” list of the “Changes” tab in the Team Explorer (so the addition would be included in the next commit).

If that isn’t the case, then you should check whether the file appears in the “Excluded Changes” list, or even the “Untracked Files” list of the Team Explorer. You can add the file easily from both using the context menu on the file.

Please take also note of this icon that’s selected in your Solution Explorer:

[image: “Show All Files” option]

This means that the Solution Explorer will show files that are not part of your project. Make sure that the file you are trying to add is actually part of the project to ensure that Visual Studio will see it in the Team Explorer (it also shows files not part of the project in the untracked list, but just to be sure, check that it’s part of the project).

Comment: Yea my files go to the "excluded changes" even though I added them from within Visual Studio, but I don't want it to do that. I want it to automatically just include those files. So that it prevents the coder from having to go to the Team Explorer and adding them manually. I know it is easy, but it is very easy to forget so I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: I tried to replicate that for a while, but all files I add within Visual Studio are automatically added to the included list :/

Comment: Yea you're right. Thanks. My problem seems to be different because someone else had added new files to the project. I got the files by syncing, and then I changed the name of the files (from within VS). Apparently changing names of files that other people brought into VS is problematic because it does not add the file to the included list automatically.